# Why is `source` used in the .bash_profile with virtualenvwrapper?

Tags: python, bash, macos, virtualenvwrapper

`virtualenvwrapper` instructs us to put `source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` in our `.bash_profile`. Why?

I see it creates `.virtualenvs` the first time it's run. Is `.virtualenvs` newly created every time I `$ source .bash_profile`? If yes, is this so `.virtualenvs` can be updated as `virtualenvwrapper` is updated?

Comment: This might help: `help source`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just a helper module to bind your shell and `virtualenvwrapper` together. It defines such helpers as:

- `workon` to activate a `virtualenv`
- `mkvirtualenv` to create new ones
- `rmvirtualenv` to delete unused `virtualenv`s
- and some other commands, type `virtualenvwrapper` to see the full list

When you are `source`ing something it is [pretty much the same](https://superuser.com/questions/46139/what-does-source-do) as `import`ing in `python`. And no, it does not create `~/.virtualenvs` folder each time.

It also does some preparations: checking that `~/.virtualenvs` folder is in place and that hooks are executed properly.

You can always see the source code of this file by running: `cat /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`.